# Can someone explain how this question is reduced using basic postulates

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm looking at some class examples on basic postulates and I can't figure out how the 2nd part is reduced (see below). Could someone explain it to me?

eq:

```
X='a'c+ac+'ac+a'c
```

this is the part I do not understand, and could use some explanation using the formulas below.

```
= 'a('c+c) + a('c+c)
```

The example uses theses formulas:

```
[p6a] x*y = y*x
[p8a] x(y+z) = x*y + x*z
```

and to finish it all off: (which I understand)

```
= 'a*1 + a*1
= 'a+a
= 1
```

Comment: You are also using commutativity of addition, right? (x+y=y+x) And associativity, perhaps? ((a+b)+c=a+(b+c))

Comment: looking at http://www.docstoc.com/docs/46343808/Basic-Postulate-and-Theorems-of-Boolean-Algebra those might be [p6b] and [p7b]

Comment: @Henry, I agree as well. In the handout's it states p6a and p8a however I have a feeling that may have been a typo. I'll run it by the prof next class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be completely explicit: we begin with the formula $$X = a' c' + ac + a'c+ac'$$ (where I have written 'c as $c'$ in order to make the latex easier). We then switch the second and third terms:

$$X = a' c' + a' c + ac + ac'.$$

We can now apply p8a (in "reverse", as it were):

$$X = a' (c' + c) + a (c + c').$$

Finally, we reorder the terms inside the second set of parentheses:

$$X = a' (c' + c) + a (c' + c),$$

and you can take it from here.

Note that this derivation doesn't use p6a (the commutativity of multiplication), but it *does* use the commutativity of addition.

**Edit:** As Henry pointed out in the comments above, your class might be calling the commutativity of addition p6b.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense now! I think what I had confusing me was x+y = y+x, in that I could only move a single variable and not a term.